# Visual Studio 2013 Integrated Git Version

Tags: git, visual-studio

I would like to know how does the Git version work with Visual Studio 2013. For example, Git had some vulnerability issue as described here: https://github.com/blog/1938-git-client-vulnerability-announced
In that case, we would have to update our Git client for the best practice. How does the integrated Git work in Visual Studio 2013? Does it sync with the Git version installed on your laptop? Do we have to manually upgrade the Git version comes with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not call out to a git client.  It uses a library ([libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)) to perform Git repository operations.

Microsoft worked closely with the git core, msysgit and libgit2 projects to ensure that CVE-2014-9390 was fixed responsibly, and announced patches to Visual Studio that include fixes for this vulnerability.  For detailed information about Visual Studio updates, please see Brian Harry's blog: [Git vulnerability with .git\config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/12/18/git-vulnerability-with-git-config.aspx)